# Circuit for finding engine RPM using the magneto's coil ground wire

Tags: transistors, ac, frequency, electromagnetism, high-voltage

I'm looking to see if there's a solution without using a microcontroller to find the engine RPM (perhaps spark frequency is a better term?) using only the magneto's coil grounding wire. This wire kills the engine when you touch it to the block. I believe this wire carries an AC current (correct me if I'm wrong) and a high voltage, so I was not sure how I could go about designing a simple circuit that won't be killed by these two factors.

I basically want to turn a transistor off once a certain frequency has been achieved. The transistor is normally on until this frequency has been reached.

I've seen engine hour meters and tachometers that clip onto or wrap around the spark plug wire, but that isn't what I'm trying to do in this case. I'm pretty sure there is a frequency on the grounding wire too, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I'd appreciate any help offered.

Here's a crude picture of the magneto setup:

[image]

Comment: if you can tap into/sense the frequency of it's firing, you can use a frequency -> voltage converter op-amp style IC. Have you looked at this option yet?

Comment: @KyranF yes, I posted a similar question using a hall effect sensor and the answerer said to go with an LM2917, but I've had no luck getting it to work, so I thought to just try to use the coil's grounding wire instead of a sensor (less parts).

Comment: Can you describe more the actual 'signal' you are trying to measure? what does it look like? how does it behave? there may be easy ways to measure/use it..

Comment: @KyranF no I can't, I was hoping someone here would know a typical magneto output.

Comment: Is it a HT mag, or an energy transfer mag (external coil)?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not an engine guy.  But I think you'd want a voltage divider to scale the voltage down.  And it's going to reduce your spark voltage.    I bet if you wrapped an insulated wire around the spark plug line there would be enough capacitive pickup to see the spark.  But I always seem to get "bitten" if I play around with the spark wires while the engine is running.  Maybe a little magnet on the flywheel and a reed relay.  (That gets away from all the HV issues.)

Comment: well I guess it has some current flowing somewhere, so you could whack a current sense resistor and current shunt monitor, and use a simple Counter IC to count the leading edges of the shunt monitor's output.. depends just how crazy and if it's AC/DC style, if you can get the type of magneto might help others with their answers

Comment: It's a standard Briggs & Stratton magneto, mower style. They're pretty basic. I'd like to not have to wrap anything around the spark plug wire; I just want to use the grounding wire.

Comment: well maybe using the ground wire isnt the best way to do it?? As I was saying, detecting current flow with a shunt resistor in the pathway (series) is something you could do.

Comment: Why wouldn't a shunt work in series in the small ground out wire?

Comment: Ok, I believe that's an energy transfer magneto. It is basically a combined low-voltage magneto and step-up transformer. My guess is the ground wire is just the "high" side of the primary winding, which when shorted to ground stops the higher voltage being generated.

Comment: So it will be an AC waveform, and the voltage will be whatever the low-voltage side of the magneto generates.  But check that first ;)

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle you're probably right, I can see a spark jump from the small wire to the block. Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Comment: You'd need to know what the voltage is, and then you can use a voltage divider to reduce it to a more sensible voltage for sensing.

Comment: I tried hooking my multimeter up to this wire while the engine was running, but it was very sporadic and impossible to get a reading.

Comment: I just found this very useful document: http://www.uidaho.edu/~/media/Files/orgs/CALS/Department/AEE/Curriculum/Curriculum%20guides/200%20level/221Title%20page%20Acknowledgements%20and%20Contents/221I1%20Ignition%20Theory.ashx - seems to tell us all there is to know about your magneto.

Comment: "The rapid change in magnetism produces 170 volts in the primary winding."

Comment: I wasn't able to concur from the document if the small wire I describe is on the spark plug (secondary) side or the primary side.

Comment: My guess is it is in parallel with the breaker points. Having it on the secondary side would be kind of silly, with 10,000V flowing through it, when there is already a mechanism to turn the sparks on and off on the low voltage side.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle my engine doesn't have points and condensor like the document showed. Older engines had them.

Comment: Would a full wave rectifier to convert the ~170 VAC to DC, a smoothing cap, a voltage divider, and some circuit to charge a cap and resistor (values to be determined from RPM i need) be adequate enough to turn a transistor off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18106/discussion-between-troop231-and-majenko-not-google).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is to make a crude optoisolator using a phototransistor and a neon tube. enclose both inside a plastic camera film canister to shield from external light sources. 3 or 4 turns around the high voltage lead going to one lead of the neon bulb, the other goes neon bulb lead is grounded. Cheap, easy, not very time consuming and gives your tach circuit a lot of high voltage isolation.